# WebSphere Contextlistener not authenticated

Tags: authentication, websphere

We have as application which where ported from WAS 5 to WAS 8. After some changes I found that context listener is not executed as authenticated user.

We have following web-app definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>InDiaServerMonitoring</display-name>
    <listener>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>
        Timer Control Listener</display-name>
        <listener-class>servlet.TimerControlListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>
        MonitoringServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>MonitoringServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.MonitoringServlet</servlet-class>
        <run-as>
            <role-name>monitor</role-name>
        </run-as>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MonitoringServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MonitoringServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>monitor</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <ejb-local-ref id="EJBLocalRef_1213267259466">
        <description>
        </description>
        <ejb-ref-name>ejb/Service</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <local-home>business.ServiceControllerLocalHome</local-home>
        <local>business.ServiceControllerLocal</local>
        <ejb-link>Services.jar#ServiceController</ejb-link>
    </ejb-local-ref>
</web-app>
```

We would like to execute custom code on ServiceController which require user (any user) to be authenticated. We have deffined user for monitoring page to be used. Actually monitoring page is accessible without user authentication, but inside listener we are getting not authorised exception like:

```
javax.ejb.AccessLocalException:  ; nested exception is: com.ibm.websphere.csi.CSIAccessException: SECJ0053E: Authorization failed for None/server:iap_iapnode0_server while invoking (Bean)Prj#EJB.jar#ServiceController stopTimers::3  is not granted any of the required roles: user 
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityCollaborator.performAuthorization(SecurityCollaborator.java:626)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.EJSSecurityCollaborator.preInvoke(EJSSecurityCollaborator.java:265)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeAfterActivate(EJSContainer.java:4214)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.EjbPreInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3481)
at business.EJSLocalCSLServiceController_f7e0e567.stopTimers(EJSLocalCSLItrServiceController_f7e0e567.java)
at monitoring.servlet.TimerControlListener.contextInitialized(TimerControlListener.java:70)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1164)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:770)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1361)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2162)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5468)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5594)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1251)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:578)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1819)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.csi.CSIAccessException: SECJ0053E: Authorization failed for None/server:iap_iapnode0_xd while invoking (Bean)InDiaPrj#InDiaTBItrEJB.jar#ItrServiceController stopTimers::3  is not granted any of the required roles: user 
... 112 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Context listener cannot have any run as role associated with it.
You are trying to invoke  `(Bean)Prj#EJB.jar#ServiceController stopTimers` from that context listener, which looks like is secured and requires `user` which is not accessible by anonymous users.

So you have following solutions:

1) Use programmatic login in your context, with similar code to this:

```
// create login context
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext( "WSLogin", new WSCallbackHandlerImpl(userid, password));
// do login
lc.login();
// retrieve subject
Subject subject = lc.getSubject();
// set new identity
WSSubject.setRunAsSubject(subject);
// call session bean
itrServiceController.stopTimers();
// logout - destroy credentials
lc.logout();
```

2) Use intermediate servlet or EJB with runas role set.

So from your listener you just call servlet or local session bean, which will have runAs role set, and that bean will simply call your `ItrServiceController` using associated with role user.

This is probably easier as it allows to define that user/role mapping on deployment.

Comment: Actually both parts are defined in one project, which has defined one role monitoring in runasuser with user, which is working fine for monitoring page (where this context listener is notified), but that user is not used for That Controller where any authenticated user is required

Comment: @JanPešta Hmm I didnt get you explanation. Servlet context is not notified by the page, but by the container when the app is started.

Comment: The monitoring servlet is about monitoring application state, and there this servlet has runAsUser defined for role monitoring. The think is that monitoring and ServiceController are in same project where runAsUser is defined for monitoring and ServiceController has access level on any authenticated user.